Error during npm install: Issues with deprecated packages and node-gyp rebuild compatibility
I am currently working on a Node.js project and encountered issues while trying to install the necessary packages using npm install. During the installation process, I received multiple deprecation warnings for certain packages, indicating that they are no longer maintained or should be upgraded. Additionally, the installation fails with an error related to the x509 package, which appears to involve node-gyp and compilation issues.
Despite having the correct versions of Node.js and npm installed, the build process for the native module fails, resulting in several compilation errors. This has halted my progress, and I'm unsure how to resolve these issues effectively.
I have tried checking the compatibility of the packages with my Node.js version, but the errors persist. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to address both the deprecation warnings and the installation error.
Warnings:
npm warn deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm warn deprecated node-webcrypto-ossl@1.0.49: node-webcrypto-ossl has been deprecated. This module was created in 2015 because at the time the Node team did not feel the need to have two crypto interfaces and they already had one before WebCrypto was defined.

Error Message:
npm error path /Users/rohail/Documents/Github/node-version-to-20/node_modules/x509
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm error CXX(target) Release/obj.target/x509/src/addon.o
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.2.0
npm error gyp info using node@22.12.0 | darwin | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.5 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
npm error gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args '/Users/rohail/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'make',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/Users/rohail/Documents/Github/node-version-to-20/node_modules/x509/build/config.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/Users/rohail/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/rohail/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/rohail/Documents/Github/node-version-to-20/node_modules/x509',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'build',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp info spawn make
npm error gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm error In file included from ../src/addon.cc:5:
npm error In file included from ../include/x509.h:7:
npm error In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:174:
npm error ../node_modules/nan/nan_callbacks.h:55:23: error: no member named 'AccessorSignature' in namespace 'v8'
npm error typedef v8::Local<v8::AccessorSignature> Sig;
npm error                   ~~~~^
npm error In file included from ../src/addon.cc:5:
npm error In file included from ../include/x509.h:7:
npm error ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2536:8: error: no matching member function for call to 'SetAccessor'
npm error   tpl->SetAccessor(
npm error   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm error /Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/include/node/v8-template.h:1055:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::AccessControl' to 'v8::PropertyAttribute' for 5th argument
npm error   void SetAccessor(
npm error        ^
npm error /Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/include/node/v8-template.h:1049:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'imp::NativeGetter' (aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &)') to 'v8::AccessorGetterCallback' (aka 'void (*)(Local<v8::String>, const PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &)') for 2nd argument
npm error   void SetAccessor(
npm error        ^
npm error In file included from ../src/addon.cc:5:
npm error In file included from ../include/x509.h:7:
npm error In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2884:
npm error ../node_modules/nan/nan_typedarray_contents.h:34:43: error: no member named 'GetContents' in 'v8::ArrayBuffer'
npm error       data   = static_cast<char*>(buffer->GetContents().Data()) + byte_offset;
npm error                                   ~~~~~~~~^
npm error In file included from ../src/addon.cc:4:
npm error In file included from ../include/addon.h:4:
npm error In file included from /Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/include/node/node.h:73:
npm error In file included from /Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/include/node/v8.h:24:
npm error In file included from /Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:12:
npm error /Users/rohail/Library/Caches/node-gyp/22.12.0/include/node/v8-local-handle.h:269:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_base_of<v8::Value, v8::Data>::value' "type check"
npm error     static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, S>::value, "type check");
npm error     ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm error ../node_modules/nan/nan_callbacks_12_inl.h:175:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Value>::Local<v8::Data>' requested here
npm error       cbinfo(info, obj->GetInternalField(kDataIndex));
npm error                    ^
npm error 4 errors generated.
npm error make: *** [Release/obj.target/x509/src/addon.o] Error 1
npm error gyp ERR! build error 
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/rohail-invozone/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:216:23)
npm error gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
npm error gyp ERR! command "/Users/rohail/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/bin/node" "/Users/rohail-invozone/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd /Users/rohail-invozone/Documents/Github/node-version-to-20/node_modules/x509
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v22.12.0
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.2.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok

Environment

Node Version: 22.12.0
npm Version: 10.2.0
OS: macOS Darwin 21.5.0

package.json file
  "name": "version-to-20",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.21.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^7.4.1",
    "got": "^14.4.5",
    "x509": "git+https://github.com/lvhdev/node-x509"
  }
}


Wouldn't it be easier to port the code to Node's built-in parser? https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-x509certificate
